# react native video not playing in iPhone 13

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, video

I have an prod app which used  Video from 'react-native-video' for displaying video that the user captures and I've found that the captured video is not getting played only for iPhone 13 devices
rest all iphones seems to work just fine same with android no issue playing
could anyone help debug/solve this issue

I've tried recreating this issue on simulator but on simulator since I can't access camera I've downloaded random video through react-native-fs and used it's uri to play in video tag source it seems to work fine on iPhone 13 simulator